# FCM received notification from php didn't work from my server and work from admin

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem when receive  a notification from my server php code but it works good when i send it from admin of firebase.

I get server key from settings in firebase project and get browser key and try with both and didn't work

here is the code of php :

```
function sendToAndroid($DevicesTokens, $ID, $Message) {

    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $_Message = array(
        'id' => $ID,
        'message' => $Message
            );
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => array($DevicesTokens),
        'data' => $_Message,
    );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

here is the response in json

{\"multicast_id\":4977823335719589401,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:1475538722422633%584545e6f9fd7ecd\"}]}

and the android code is :

```
         public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
        // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
        // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
        // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
        // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
        // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification


         if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MessageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("message",messageBody);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.like_icon)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

     public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseIIDService";


     @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);


        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // TODO: Implement this method to send token to your app server.
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("Token",token)
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://192.168.1.71/fcm/register.php")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        try {
            client.newCall(request).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I think the problem is from my php code because it works fine from firebase admin for specific token and for all.

I sent the device token and saved in database.

Comment: Are you receiving any error response?

Comment: no I get success response

Answer (score 1):

You have to use FCM code for php and android in both

Here is the full working code code of php

```
$msg = "Hello Zamin";
$device_id = 'Your device token';`

$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
               $fields = array (
                      'to' => $device_id,
                      'notification' => array (
                              "body" => $msg,
                              'title'   => "iorder",
                              "icon" => "myicon"
                      )
              );
            $fields = json_encode ( $fields );
            $headers = array (

                    'Authorization: key=' . "Your Server id",
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

            $ch = curl_init ();
            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
            curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields );

            echo $result = curl_exec ( $ch );
            curl_close ( $ch )
```